two-step gibbs sampling vs block gibbs sampling
While reading Bayesian-related technical articles, I can see algorithms such as two-step Gibbs sampling and block gibbs sampling algorithms. It seems to me that they have quite some similarities. I would like to understand more on their differences and their respective implementation details. Any insightful explanations are appreciated. Thank you!

I would suggest you first invest in reading the relevant literature, eg a textbook on Bayesian computational methods like McElreath.
